# I plan on giving away old computers : to protect my personal data, is it enough to remove the hard drives?

Tags: deletion

I have a desktop from ~2009 and a laptop from 2014 (Samsung NP700Z7C) that I'd like to give away so people can reuse parts if they wish to.

However, I don't want to take any risks regarding personal data (both were my personal PCs, with all my life on the drive).

Is removing the hard drive enough of a security measure to prevent access to any personal information, or can data be stored elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I personally would clear the TPM too.  The data associated with TPM include Bitlocker encryption keys, passkey secrets, etc.

Make sure you have exported any Bitlocker recovery keys, if necessary, and have alternative login method if you use windows to store passkeys / FIDO2 2FA credentials.

See https://passage.1password.com/post/eli5-how-does-a-tpm-work for additional info on the kinds of information stored on TPM.  Clearing the TPM is in the "Security processor troubleshooting" screen (Windows 11).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be fine. Your RAM is temporary storage and everything else can't have long term storage either.

Comment: How do you know about the SSD which might cache frequently used data from the HDD including private document and information?

Comment: It seems like he is talking about the in-built hard drives, so I would assume he doesn't have an SSD in there. Now if there is, that is another story. Then you would have to wipe the SSD. Apologies for the mistake.